# Why does the address operator come as a default member of C++ class and what is it?

Tags: c++, address-operator

There are 5 default members in C++ classes. Default constructor, destructor, copy constructor, assignment operator and address operator.

1. What is an address operator? Is it `className* operator &() {}`?
2. If so, why does the compiler generate this address operator by default (as we already have an address operator in C and we can get the address of an object without this extra overhead)?
   Is there any special purpose?

Comment: There's no implicit `operator &()` member, the built-in operator is used when you write `&obj`, and overloading it is generally a spectacularly bad idea.

Comment: And you seem to have left out move-ctor and move-assignment, both of which will have default provision under the right circumstances.

Comment: @Satus my question is completely different.

Comment: @All Please answer to my 2nd question if possible.

Answer (score 4):

You are starting from the wrong premise. The *special member functions* are (§12 [special]/p1)

- the default constructor - implicitly declared if there is no user-declared constructor
- the copy constructor and copy assignment operator - implicitly declared if not user-declared
- the move constructor and move assignment operator - implicitly declared only if no copy/move ctor/assignment operator or destructor is user-declared
- the destructor - implicitly declared if not user-declared

The unary `operator &` is not a special member function, and there is no such thing as a compiler generated `operator &()` function. If you write

```
struct B {} b;
B *pb = &b;
```

then what is used is the built-in `&` operator. No function call or overhead involved. It behaves just like if you took the address of a `int` variable.

There are programmers who manually overload unary `operator &`. This is usually a spectacularly bad idea.

Comment: Why do you say that overloading unary `&` is a bad idea ? If you need smart pointers or things like that it is necessary.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès He said _usually_.  I would have said never, except that I recently encountered a case where it made sense.  But one exception doesn't mean that is usually a bad idea.  (And I don't see where it would be a good idea with smart pointers.)

Comment: Right I misinterpreted the "usually". Taking the address of something can give you a smart pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

In the section 13.3.1.2 of the C++ Standard concerning operator overload resolution one finds the following rule:

> If the operator is the `operator ,`, the unary `operator &`, or the `operator ->`, and there are no viable functions, then the operator is assumed to be the built-in operator and interpreted according to Clause 5.

If all types were provided with a member `operator&` by default, the viable set could never be empty.  Since there's a rule for what to do when the viable set is empty, you can therefore be sure that types initially don't have a member `operator&`.